# RxSwift: Completable concat in a deferred way

Tags: swift, rx-swift, swift-extensions

Can anybody tell me if it is possible to create a deferred completable in a concat operator.

I want to fetch a session, and after this load a user with the corresponding session id.

```
SessionAPI.post(email: email, password: password)
UserAPI.get(id: Session.load()!.userId)
```

Until now I used observables with the flatMap operator.

I will now try to reproduce the same behaviour with the completables, which doesn't have flatMap operator.

Working code with observables:

```
SessionAPI.post(email: email, password: password)
          .flatMap { (_) -> Single<Any> in
              return UserAPI.get(id: Session.load()!.userId)
          }
```

New working code with completables

```
SessionAPI.post(email: email, password: password)
          .concat(Completable.deferred { UserAPI.get(id: Session.load()!.userId) } )
```

I now want to create an extension for this deferred completable, like:

```
SessionAPI.post(email: email, password: password)
          .concatDeferred(UserAPI.get(id: Session.load()!.userId))
```

Current extension:

```
extension PrimitiveSequenceType where Self.Element == Never, Self.Trait == RxSwift.CompletableTrait {

    func concatDeferred(_ second: RxSwift.Completable) -> RxSwift.Completable {
        return Completable.deferred { () -> PrimitiveSequence<CompletableTrait, Never> in
            return second
        }
    }
}
```

**Issue:** The Session.load()! in UserAPI.get is loaded and crashing before SessionAPI.post finished.

Does someone got an idea to get this extension up running?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the reason you want to defer your `UserAPI.get(id:)` is because some "magic" is happening in the background where `SessionAPI.post(email:password:)` is making it so `Session.load()` is valid.

What this tells me is that the `post(email:password:)` should *not* be completable in the first place. Rather it should return an `Observable<T>` where T is whatever Session.load() returns.

You *can't* make the code work like you want:

```
SessionAPI.post(email: email, password: password)
    .concatDeferred(UserAPI.get(id: Session.load()!.userId))
```

With the above code, `Session.load()` will get called before `SessionAPI.post(email:password:)` is even called no matter what code you put in `concatDeferred`.

The `Session.load()` function *must* be called before `concatDeferred` is so that the former can pass its result into the latter.